# Group texts of an HTML tag in list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to extract text of a tag. When I print, I get these three blocks, each belongs to a tag.

```py
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>


<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

That tag returns at least 2 strings which if I append them to a `list`, will look like this:

```py
[<class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>, 
 <class 'str'>]
```

Instead, I want to have each block be in a tuple where only two of the strings are needed. Like this:

```py
[(<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>), 
 (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>), 
 (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)]
```

I tried the following, but I struggled:

```py
e = []
for element in soup.select('div.ph0.pv2.artdeco-card.mb2 li'):
    names = element.select('div.entity-result__content.entity-result__divider.pt3.pb3.t-12.t-black--light')[0].select('a')
    if len(names) > 1:  ## filter those tags <a></a> with extra information     
        for c in names:
            print(c.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True))
```

---

**Update:**

Here, I give a real example.
The following is the output of the above code snippet.

```
LexisNexis
3 people from your school were hired here
82 jobs

AbacusNext
1 person from your school was hired here
24 jobs

Aderant
38 jobs
```

The expected output I am trying to solve is something like:

```py
[('LexisNexis', '82'), 
 ('AbacusNext', '24'), 
 ('Aderant', '38')]
```

The HTML page I am working on can be publicly found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gkj590vt/).

To separate numbers from text, I used

```py
import re
regex = re.compile('[^0-9]')
regex.sub('', <not sure what should be here based on my desired output>)
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want please add the link of the website you are scrapping and a real example of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find a good pattern and select your elements more specific:

```
data=[]
for e in soup.select('a[href*="jobs/search"]'):
    data.append((
        e.find_previous('span',{'class':'entity-result__title-text'}).get_text(strip=True),
        e.get_text(strip=True).split()[0]
    ))
data
```

or

```
data=[]
for e in soup.select('.reusable-search__result-container:has(a[href*="jobs/search"])'):
    data.append((
        e.select_one('span.entity-result__title-text').get_text(strip=True),
        e.select_one('a[href*="jobs/search"]').get_text(strip=True).split()[0]
    ))
data
```

Output:

```
[('LexisNexis', '82'),
 ('AbacusNext', '24'),
 ('Aderant', '38'),
 ('Anaqua', '3'),
 ('Thomson Reuters Elite', '1'),
 ('Litify', '6')]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get `href` using `e.find_previous('span',{'class':'entity-result__title-text'}).get_text(strip=True)`?

Comment: `e.find_previous('span',{'class':'entity-result__title-text'}).a.get('href')`